# PHP error when using date_diff() function within DataTables $columns array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, datatables

Forgive me, this is a long one. I want to give all the background for this question.

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) server-side processing for a project. My goal is to utilize the `echo` function to `echo` the number of days between today's date and dates in a column of my database called CreatedDate, which is a DateTime type.

I was trying to get the basic functionality working outside of DataTables first, and the function below works as intended, and outputs an `$current_date` of the number of days between `$date` and `$date` as: "16 days live", "15 days live", etc.:

```
$sql = "SELECT CreatedDate FROM Estimates";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $created_date = $row["CreatedDate"];
  $date = new DateTime($created_date);
  $current_date = new DateTime();
  $diff = date_diff($date, $current_date);
  echo $diff->format('%d days live');
 }
 } else {
 echo "No results";
 }
```

In my DataTables `$columns` array, I am trying to achieve the same effect:

```
// date variable
$created_date = 'CreatedDate';
$current_date = new DateTime();

// array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// the 'db' parameter represents the column name in the database, while the 'dt'
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier.
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'Client', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'EstimateNumber', 'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'Status', 'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'CurrentEstimateTotal', 'dt' => 3 ),
array(
  'db' => $created_date,
  'dt' => 4,
  'formatter' =>
        function ($created_date, $row) use ($current_date) {
        $date = new DateTime($created_date);
        $diff = date_diff($date, $current_date);
        echo $diff->format('%d days live');
     }
)
);
```

I keep recieving an error of:

`PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.`

How can I fix this? I am having a hard time getting a var_dump() of the `$created_date` and `$date` variables within the DataTables array to see what the problem is.

For more information about DataTables server-side processing, [I am using this template as a base for my DataTables script.](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) The DataTables script also uses [this helper class.](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return your string from callback.

```
'formatter' =>
        function ($created_date, $row) use ($current_date) {
        $date = new DateTime($created_date);
        $diff = date_diff($date, $current_date);
        return $diff->format('%d days live'); //That will solve your problem
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need to `return` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Closure have to return something, so somewhere deep inside of 'datatable.com' code it will initiate some object based on it. It's hard to imaging closure without return as we usually need a result:)